# a href to a new browser with embedded video

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out how to format a posted youtube link so that it embeds video but does so in a new browser window (the page auto refreshes every ten seconds, so embedding video directly onto the page is a problem.  Also, I'm aware that it would be smarter to have the page update asynchronously, but I'm not there yet.)

So, for example;

1) A user posts the link `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=examplevideo`.  I can use a regex expression to change it so that it can be an embedded video on the page, but because of my limitation, I would need it to be an embedded video on a new page.  So, instead, I would change this link to be;

2) `http://img.youtube.com/vi/examplevideo/0.jpg`.  This image (standard syntax for all posted youtube video) would be posted on the page instead.  In clicking this image, it would open a new tab or browser and start playing an embedded video for that new page.  The syntax for the embedded video, consistent with this scenario, is;

3) `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/examplevideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

So, I know that I can use "a href" syntax to add a link to the image so that anyone who clicks on it will be taken to the link on youtube.  I'm assuming that a similar method would be used to point to a new browser page with the embedded video on it?  How would this work?

Comment: How do you want to perform a regular expression with HTML? Are you using any programming languages? Add proper tags, please.

Comment: Hi matewka, I'll leave regex out for the time being - I'm just looking for a way to add a clickable link to an image so that when the image is click a new browser window opens showing the embedded video.  How would the syntax for this image look?

Comment: I understand your question. I just wanted to know what languages you allow to use to provide you an answer. Nevermind now, there is an answer that should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `target` attribute of the `a` element to `_blank` to open it in a new tab or window.

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zX54DIpacNE" target=_blank>Clicky</a>
```

Although IMHO it's better to just link to the youtube page of the video instead of embedding it since you are opening it in a new tab already.

Comment: I think you're right.  It would be easier and neater.  But, as you can tell, html is not my strong suit, so I'm not 100% sure if I'm aware of all the options.